# SSRS chart should look like my excel chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am doing an SSRS report which needs to have a chart that looks like this

[Excel chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWzUw.png)

and so far on my ssrs report I have this

[SSRS chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0dtu.png)

how could I make my ssrs chart the same on my excel chart?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to put all your data together. You want to compare different years with the same date. You'll need to change your date field to just use the month and day:

```
=FORMAT(FIELDS!YourDateField.Value, "MM-dd")
```

For the axis label, use the Day of the Week:

```
=FORMAT(FIELDS!YourDateField.Value, "dw")
```

[image]

For your **markers**, go to Series Properties->Markers tab and set Marker Type to Auto to let SSRS assign a different type to each. If each year is a different series, you can assign them individually.

You can right-click on an Axis and go to properties to format them to look more like the Excel version.

There's a bit more differences but mostly formatting.